# HTML button on expressjs server run node.js script

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a button in HTML:

`<button id="save" type="button" onclick="save()">Save</button>`

and in javascript I want it to run something in node.js, something that's not client side.

So something like this is what I am looking for:

```js
function save() {
    //run script from server
}
```

And if this script MUST be ran as if I was typing `node script.js`

The reason the script has to be ran as if I was typing it was because it's saving a file to the node.js server, a json to be exact, and that file must be on the node.js server for my application.

Answer (score 2):

So you really can't execute a server-function from the client side, but you can maybe send a post-request and call the function on the server side, or you can use sockets to communicate with the server. Either way, it would be horrible security-wise, if you would be able to interact with the server on that way.